# Set responsive HTML backgrounds

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good day, I have a simple webpage with two background images. So here is my css

```
body{
      background:
            url('<?=base_url();?>/assets/header_bg.png')no-repeat ,
            url('<?=base_url();?>/assets/footer_bg.png')no-repeat;    
          background-size: contain;

      background-position: 100px -30px, 0px 98%;
      -webkit-background-size: contain;
      -moz-background-size: contain;
      -o-background-size: contain;
    }
```

And here is the result (I will only take the top section and the footer section)

Top section home:

[image]

Top section about page:

[image]

And then the problem, home bottom section:

[image]

and about bottom section:

[image]

as you can see, the bg image in about page is not full. Any solution(s) for this ?

BTW, I'm using codeigniter. Here is my full page

My Main

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Lesfemmes</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url();?>assets/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url();?>assets/css/flexslider.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>

html{
  height: auto;
  width:  auto ;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Bookcustom;
    src: url('<?=base_url();?>assets/fonts/gothamfamily/Gotham-Book.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Boldcustom;
    src: url('<?=base_url();?>assets/fonts/gothamfamily/Gotham-Bold.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Forquote;
    src: url('<?=base_url();?>assets/fonts/gothamfamily/ufonts.com_baskerville-italic.ttf');
}


.navbar{
    font-family: Bookcustom;
    font-size: 16pt;
}

      @media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav{
        float:none;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
    } 


}
.fixed-bottom {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}


.navbar.transparent.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {

    border-width: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50.00% 0.00%, 50.00% 100.00%, color-stop( 0% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00)),color-stop( 100% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
  }

.navbar.transparent ul.nav a:hover 
{ 
  background-color: transparent; !important; 
  color: #efa0c0
}

#topnavbar{
  top: 15px;
}


.navbar a {
    color: black;
    font-family: Bookcustom;
    font-size: 16pt;
}


.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}


h3.subjudul{
  font-family: Boldcustom;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

h3.thumbnail{
   font-family: Boldcustom;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

blockquote{
  border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
  }
.navbar-bottom {
    margin-top:40px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: Bookcustom;
    font-size: 16pt;

}

.back-to-top {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
}
.back-to-top:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 1;
} 
.fa-arrow-up:hover {
  color: white;
}
.fa-arrow-up {
  color: black;
}
table th.fit {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1%;
}


div.c-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
.carousel-inner{
  width:100%;

}
.peopleCarouselImg img {
  width: auto;
  height: 225px;
  max-height: 225px;
}
.subscribe{
  bottom: 45px;
}
.carousel-control{
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {

  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 115px
}

.quotecontent{
font-family: Forquote; 
font-style: italic;
font-size: 24pt;
}

.quoteautor{
    font-family: Bookcustom;
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-align: right;
}

.about{
  padding-top: 80px;
   font-family: Bookcustom;
}
.abouttext{
  padding-top: 60px;
   font-family: Bookcustom;
}
.youtubeabout{
  margin-top: -350px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.box{
  padding-top: 100px;
  background:#F9D7E8;
  padding:15px;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
   position:relative;
     margin-left: 110px;
     margin-top: 120px;
}
.box-inner{
  border:1px solid #000;
  height:100%; 
}
.box p {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 140%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 113px;
  background: #f9d7e8;

}
.box p::before {
  background: #000;
  bottom: -2px;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  left: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 18px;  
  width: 35px;
  z-index: -1;
}
#bottomnavbar{

   margin-bottom: -20px;
}
body{

    background:
        url('<?=base_url();?>/assets/header_bg.png')no-repeat ,
        url('<?=base_url();?>/assets/footer_bg.png')no-repeat;    
      background-size: contain;

  background-position: 100px -30px, 0px 98%;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
}
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container-fullwidth">
 <a id="back-to-top" href="#" class="back-to-top" role="button" data-placement="left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-2x"></i></a>
 <div class="asheader">
  <div id="Intro" class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-5">
    <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/logo_hitam.png" width="200px" height="50px">
  </div>


    <nav id="topnavbar" class="navbar transparent col-md-offset-2 col-md-9">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="<?=base_url();?>">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?=base_url();?>about">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?=base_url();?>product">Product</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?=base_url();?>promo">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?=base_url();?>competition">Competition</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?=base_url();?>ladiesroom">Ladies Room</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?=base_url();?>help">Need Help?</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--- -->
    </nav>
    <div class="row content container-fluid">
      <?php $this->load->view($include);?>
      </div>
      <nav id="bottomnavbar" class="navbar navbar-static-bottom navbar-inverse col-md-12 fixed-bottom">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Promo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Competition</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ladies Room</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Need Help?</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--- -->
    </nav>
    </div>
</div>
 <script  src="assets/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
 <script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
      $('.navbar').removeClass('transparent');
      $('.navbar').toggleClass('navbar-default');
    }
    else {
      $('.navbar').toggleClass('transparent');
      $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-default');
    }
    })
})
 $(document).ready(function() {
              $('.slide_thumb').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                controlNav: false,
                animationLoop: false,
                slideshow: false,
                itemWidth: 210,
                itemMargin: 5,
                asNavFor: '.slide_thumb',
                itemWidth: 210,
                itemMargin: 5,
                minItems: 4,
                maxItems: 4
            });
            });
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $('#back-to-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#back-to-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });
        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#back-to-top').click(function () {
            $('#back-to-top').tooltip('hide');
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });

        $('#back-to-top').tooltip('show');

});
 $(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 2000
    });
});
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My welcome page (Home),

```
<div style="margin-top: 100px" class="c-wrapper text-center col-md-offset-5 col-md-6">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="active item">
    <img class="peopleCarouselImg" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x300/">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img class="peopleCarouselImg" src="assets/banner-free-gift.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item"> 
       <img class="peopleCarouselImg" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/000">
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
  </div>
</div>


    <div class="lookbook col-md-offset-2 col-md-9 text-center">
      <h3 class="subjudul">Lookbook</h3>
      <div id="" class="flexslider slide_thumb">
          <ul class="slides">
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
  </div>



<div class="grid col-md-offset-2 col-md-9 text-center">
    <table class="table" style="display:block" >
        <tr>
            <td>
          <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/mini-banner.jpg" width="80%">
      </td>
            <td>     
          <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/mini-banner.jpg" width="80%">
      </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>     
          <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/mini-banner.jpg" width="80%">
            </td>
            <td>              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/mini-banner.jpg" width="80%">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </div>



    <div
          class="quote col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 text-center">
 <blockquote class="quote-card">
              <p class="quotecontent">
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit." 
              </p>

              <p class="quoteautor">
                Lorem I psum
              </p>
            </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="lookbook col-md-offset-2 col-md-9 text-center">
      <h3 class="subjudul">Ladies Room</h3>
     <div class = "col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <div class = "thumbnail">
         <img src = "<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail">
      </div>

      <div class = "caption">
         <h3 class="thumbnail">Thumbnail label</h3>

      </div>
   </div>
   <div class = "col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <div class = "thumbnail">
         <img src = "<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail">
      </div>

      <div class = "caption">
           <h3 class="thumbnail">Thumbnail label</h3>


      </div>
   </div>
   <div class = "col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <div class = "thumbnail">
         <img src = "<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail">
      </div>

      <div class = "caption">
            <h3 class="thumbnail">Thumbnail label</h3>


      </div>
   </div>
   <div class = "col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <div class = "thumbnail">
         <img src = "<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail">
      </div>

      <div class = "caption">
           <h3 class="thumbnail">Thumbnail label</h3>


      </div>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div class="instagram col-md-offset-2 col-md-9 text-center">
<h3 class="subjudul">See The Latest On Instagram</h3>
  <div id="" class="flexslider slide_thumb">
          <ul class="slides">
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

</div>
 <div class="subscribe col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 text-center">
<h3 class="subjudul">SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h3>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. 
Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>

<div class="input-group col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

and my about page

```
<style>

</style>
<div style="background-color: pink; height: 400px; margin-top: 50px" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-inner">
            <p>lorem ipsum dolar sit amet</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<iframe class="youtubeabout" width="900px" height="400px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/viWs0M5R2BLo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div class="about col-md-offset-5 col-md-5">
    <h3 class="subjudul">About Us</h3>
</div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 100px" class="abouttext col-md-offset-1 text-center col-md-10">
    <p style="text-align: center;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. </p>
    <p>
    Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>

    <p> Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting your second background's position with 98%. That means you are setting its position based on 98% *from the top*. On pages of different heights, the visual position of the background will be slightly different in absolute pixels.

Your footer appears to be about 40px high, so instead of 98%, set the value to `calc(100% - 40px)`.

Comment: @YVS1102 Yep. https://css-tricks.com/positioning-offset-background-images/